# Unable to recover an image from wikipedia API and display it in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, segue

I have an app that gets data from the Wikipedia API and displays it in another view controller. Specifically, it displays an extract / a definition from a keyword typed in a UITextField (it is displayed in a text view), and should also display the image Wikipedia used to illustrate that keyword.

My problem is that the text data is displayed in the new view controller, but not the image.

Since my app is relatively short, let me display the full code for both view controllers.

1. First the code for the view controller that gets the information from Wikipedia via HTTP call

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SDWebImage // me permet d'ajouter une image venant de wikipedia pour illustrer mon paragraphe recherché

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textEntryLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var segueButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //darkMode()
        // on appelle la fonction qui gere les couleurs alternatives lorsque dark mode est detecté
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            darkMode()
        }

    }

    //MARK: - Relevant variables
    let wikipediaURl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    var termDefinitionInfo: String = ""
    var illustration = UIImageView()
    let segueName: String = "toDefinition"

    //MARK: - Button tapped action

    @IBAction func buttonToDefinition(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // on appelle la fonction ici
        httpCall(termDefinition: textEntryLabel.text ?? "Nothing to verify")
    }

    //MARK: - handles what needs to be done prior to triggering the segue

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueName {

            if let secondVC = segue.destination as? DefinitionViewController {
                //secondVC.imageIllustrative = illustration.image
                secondVC.definition = termDefinitionInfo
                secondVC.imageIllustrative = illustration.image


            } else {
                fatalError("Could not perform request!")
            }

        }
    }

    //MARK: - NETWORKING

      func httpCall(termDefinition: String) {
        let parameters : [String:String] = [
               "format" : "json",
               "action" : "query",
               "prop" : "extracts|pageimages",
               "exintro" : "",
               "explaintext" : "",
               "titles" : termDefinition,
               "indexpageids" : "",
               "redirects" : "1",
               "pithumbsize" : "250"
               ]

          //
          request(wikipediaURl, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
              if response.result.isSuccess {
                //1. on affiche le tableau json initial
                let definitionJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value)
                print(definitionJSON)

                // 3 valeurs : pageID,definition et source de l'image
                let pageId = definitionJSON["query"]["pageids"][0].stringValue
                let pageDefinition = definitionJSON["query"]["pages"][pageId]["extract"].stringValue

                let imageSource = definitionJSON["query"]["pages"][pageId]["thumbnail"]["source"].stringValue
                //on attache ces valeurs extraites aux bonnes variables
                self.illustration.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageSource))
                self.termDefinitionInfo = pageDefinition



                // cas ou on n'a pas de definition
                if pageDefinition == "" {
                    self.termDefinitionInfo =  "Désolé,ce que vous cherchez ne se trouve pas sur Wikipedia"
                }

                // et on effectue le segue vers le second view controller ici
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDefinition", sender: self)
                print(self.termDefinitionInfo)

              } else {
                print("Error! Could not fetch data!")
            }
          }
      }

    //MARK: - FONCTION QUI GERE LES COULEURS POUR LE DARK MODE
    func darkMode() {
        //la couleur du texte de la barre de navigation ici blanc
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        // la couleur du text du placeholder ici bleu
        textEntryLabel.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Saisir ici le terme à rechercher", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue])
        // la couleur du text
        textEntryLabel.textColor = UIColor.label
        //la couleur du texte du bouton ici blanc
        segueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

        //la couleur de fonds du bouton
        segueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        //la couleur de la bordure du bouton
        segueButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        segueButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

}
```

2. Here is the code for the second view controller (that displays the extract and the image)

```
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import SDWebImage

class DefinitionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var definitionIllustrationImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionTextView: UITextView!


    // on cree deux variables pour attacher l'image illustrative et la definition

    var definition: String?
    var imageIllustrative: UIImage?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //definitionTextView.text = donnees
        definitionTextView.text = definition
       // definitionIllustrationImageView.image = imageIllustrative

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Comment: Looks like `definitionIllustrationImageView.image = imageIllustrative` is greyed out on `DefinitionViewController`

Comment: Hint: Lines starting with // are comments even if they contain valid code.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is hooked up correctly in IB, then you just need to uncomment the code that assigns the image to the image view:

change

```
// definitionIllustrationImageView.image = imageIllustrative
```

to

```
definitionIllustrationImageView.image = imageIllustrative
```

Comment: I did, it still does not display the image

Comment: Does it have a valid size? in the debug console type "po definitionIllustrationImageView.image.size"  Add a breakpoint to this line and run your app. When it stops, hold the cursor over  "definitionIllustrationImageView.image ". Does it show you a preview?